# Apache/PHP appears to be caching symbolic links for 60 seconds - how to stop it, or discover what is really caching the symlinks and stop that?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, capistrano

We have a PHP web application we are deploying to a LAMP server running CentOS 5.5 using Capistrano. Capistrano manages switching to the latest version (and rolling back) using a symlink, so our document root has to point to that symlink.

Unfortunately, we have been seeing that web requests to the PHP application still point to the previous target of the document root's symlink for exactly 60 seconds after the symlink is updated.

The only setting in the PHP config I could find that might relate to this is the `realpath_cache_ttl` setting, however this is set to 120 seconds. I couldn't find anything in apache's configuration.

We are not using APC.

Am I even looking in the right place?

Comment: Is your document root located on a local hard drive, NFS or something else?

Comment: The relevant fstab entry looks like this: "/dev/centos/slash / ext3 defaults 1 1". I guess it's on a local drive, but I could be misreading it - I don't know what /dev/centos/slash means.

Comment: Yep, a local drive. There goes my theory about NFS cache.

Comment: If you have apc check apc.stat = 0 in php.ini and change it to 0 to test this if not

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked and we're not using the apc extension, though I'd prefer to be. I'll keep an eye on that setting when I set it up later.

Answer (score 10):

Symlinks are cached by Apache, I assume you are using FollowSymLinks in your httpd.conf. You could try using SymLinksIfOwnerMatch whose call to lstat is not cached  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html#symlinks

Comment: Can you link to something that says Apache/httpd caches lstat calls please?

Answer (score 1):

apache doesn't cache symlinks but it caches locations of files a bit and if you use APC it will really do some caching. I saw this also but used fabric for deploys. The work around was doing a apache restart/reload/graceful after the change symlink.

try a graceful first, then reload then restart if all else fails

Comment: Can apache be told to do any of those things when not running as root/sudo? It is not an option for me to sudo during routine capistrano deploys.

Comment: You need to work with your sysadmin to devise a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was not Apache itself. I had to restart php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't cache symlinks (it'd be incredibly stupid to try; the filesystem cache knows a lot more about what's going on, and would be very close to as fast).  I'd `strace` the whole shebang to get a better idea of what's doing what when.

Comment: What does strace do exactly? Is it safe to run in production? This is a classic "happens in production only" issue.

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.  But really, `man strace` isn't hard.

Comment: `$ man strace
No manual entry for strace`. It's not available on my production systems. Requests for elaboration on your solution go in comments.

Comment: "Is strace safe to run in production?" and "What does strace do exactly?" aren't requests for elaboration, they're completely separate questions.

Comment: It's a moot point - it's not available on the system where the problem is occurring anyway. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Install strace.

Comment: That isn't an option. I don't have control over the packages that are installed on this server. I can tinker with the configuration though.

Comment: If you don't have root, you can't properly diagnose the problem anyway, so hand this over to the sysadmin to deal with.  However, you don't need root to install software.